# Does $a^{x} + bx + c = 0$ have an analytical solution?

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus

Can $a^{x} + bx + c = 0$ be solved analytically?

Comment: What are the conditions on $a, b$ and $c$? I think that $a$ must be positive.

Comment: How can this be *Linear-Algebra*!

Comment: a is positive.  Suggestion for retag welcome.

Comment: Lambert W function.

Comment: The answer given below is correct. Let me just add my 50cents worth of rant: for "algebra-precalculus" I don't think the Lambert function counts as an analytical solution. It's basically just a function *made up* to be able to solve these types of equations. It's complicated and not many people have much intuition about it. If one uses mathematical software to solve equations then it's definately worth knowing about it. Otherwise I think that for this level the answer is "no" and equations like this should be handled by approximations or numerical methods ...

Comment: ... as it's useful for students to learn that not all equations have nice analytical solutions and there are other methods that one can apply (to expand on their tool-box for solving problems).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is **yes** in terms of [Lambert function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) and the solution would be $$x=-\frac{W(d)}{\log (a)}-\frac{c}{b}$$ using $$d=\frac{\log (a)}{b} a^{-\frac{c}{b}}$$

In fact, any equation which can write $A+Bx+C\log(D+Ex)=0$ has solution(s) in terms of Lambert function.

The Wikipedia page gives approximation formulae for small and large values of the argument $d$.